# Xamarin MVVM double click executes command twice and IsBusy doesnt work

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

So I have a button which is bound to a Login command

```
    private ICommand loginCommand;
    public ICommand LoginCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (loginCommand == null)
            {
                loginCommand = new Command(login, CanExecuteCommand);
            }
            return loginCommand;
        }
    }
```

The `CanExecuteCommand` action returns `!IsBusy`

In the login() action I start with `IsBusy = true` and end with `IsBusy = false;`
In the setter of `IsBusy` I also call the `ChangeCanExecute()` method like this:

`((Command)comm).ChangeCanExecute();`

When I am debugging `ChangeCanExecute` is really called on the command instance at the start and end of the method. However, if I double click the button, it still calls the command twice. Why is that? What's the cleanest way to disable double clicks using MVVM... By the way, on another VM I use the same approach and it works totally fine but there in the executed command I call an async method so I use `await`. Maybe that's why it works there? In the `login` case I call a `void` method in the command so if I double click the button the calls simply get queued? I still don't understand why `ChangeCanExecute+IsBusy` is not enough.

P.S.
While my commands are defined in the VM, `IsBusy, CanExecuteCommand` and the raising of the `ChangeCanExecute` event happen in the `BaseViewModel`.

Edit 1:
In `login()` I have code like this:
`{ IsBusy = true; DoSomething(); IsBusy = false;}` This has the unexpected functionality I explained and it gets called twice. However, if I change this to be in a Task like I have it in my working VM, double tap is not possible, any clues?

`IsBusy = true;
Task.Run(() =>
{
    DoSomething();
}).SafeFireAndForget();
IsBusy = false;`

I looked through answers regarding this and they don't seem to use the MVVM approach and they offer solutions using `TapGestureRecognizer` / some other things which don't seem like a best MVVM practice.

Comment: I have added an edit with an example how to make this work. However, I don't think this is the best way to do it as I really don't wanna deal with complications of async stuff and adding unnecessary usage of it, even though it's done by using the `SafeFireAndForget` extension in the nuget `AsyncAwaitBestPractices`

Comment: Is it possible that when you click the button at a second time, DoSomething(); task has finished and  IsBusy is already change to false? Then the command will be called twice.

Comment: Yes I think that's what's happening and that's why if I make it async they probably run together and it actually works....So...if that's the case what's the conclusion? I have to force all methods to be async just so that double click events dont happen in Xamarin? Or is there something that makes sense? Should I keep state instead? Not sure if that's better...Like LoginDone = true and only change it to false if it fails so that a second time cant be executed if LoginDone = true.... I don't like the idea of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, what you described is the normal behavior based on the code you using. I think whether the command will be called twice is depending on the duration between your two click events.

For example, let's say your `DoSomething();` takes 2 seconds(just an example) to finish. Then if the duration between your two click events less than 2 seconds, the command will only executed at one time and that's want you want. If the duration is more than 2 seconds, the command will be called twice.

It's the same even if you make the method async and await it.

If you want to prevent the double click in a period of time, you can just add `await Task.Delay(1000);` after  `DoSomething();` to prevent the double click in one second.

Comment: This seems to fix the issue indeed...this way I do not have to make `DoSomething()` async Task or put it in `Task.Run()` I still have to artificially decorate the `Action` for the command with `async` so that I can execute `await Task.Delay()` inside which I don't like because `async` adds a bit of performance and memory overhead..but maybe it is still better than thinking of a more overly complicated solution to the problem. Cant judge at the moment, I just know `async / await` is to be avoided if not mandatory due to the way the compiler creates a class for each `async` usage.

Comment: "what you described is the normal behavior based on the code you using." - so, to end this discussion, do you think there's an another smarter approach to this problem that I should consider, this statement made me rethink?

Comment: No, I think it's the correct way to prevent double click in a period of time. Also, using `async / await` won't affect your app's performance.